# Listar os nomes dos diretórios, de um determinado local, em um selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

Olá, estou com essa dúvida, já consegui listar os diretórios com métodos encontrados na internet, porém não consegui implementar em um método que alimente um `<h:selectOneMenu>` para que seja selecionado um item. Alguma sugestão/solução?
Obrigado.

**Para listar os diretórios**:

```
private String selectItem;
private List<SelectItem> siglas;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.modulo = new Modulo();
    getAllModulos();

    /* Listagem de diretórios para popular o SelectOneMenu */
    siglas = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    File directory = new File(".");

    File[] subdirs = directory.listFiles((FileFilter) DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
    for (File dir : subdirs) {
        siglas.add(new SelectItem(dir.getName(), dir.getName().toUpperCase()));
    } /* fim da listagem de diretórios */
}
```

Executando este método em um main, ele mostra a estrutura da aplicação, mas quando executo no Tomcat, só mostra a estrutura do sistema operacional.

**SelectOneMenu**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="siglas" value="#{moduloBean.modulo.sigla}" label="Siglas">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{moduloBean.siglas}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Adiciona seu xhtml, service e entity ao post, assim conseguimos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: post atualizado. @LeoCBS

Comment: Seu selectOneMenu está dentro de um form?

Comment: sim, se eu colocar o código do jeito que está aí, ele lista, mas apenas os diretórios do sistema Operacional, e eu gostaria de listar os diretórios da aplicação, src,main,webapps, meta-inc, web-inf. entende?